# Msg 207 Invalid Column Using CTE in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, where-clause, common-table-expression

I'm trying to reference a CTE in a WHERE clause, but I'm getting a 207 error message for an invalid column name...here's my SQL code.

```
WITH CTE (ClientNumber) AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        i.ClientKey AS ClientNumber 
    FROM 
        [PROD].[dbo].[Invoices] i  
    WHERE 
        MONTH(i.InvDate) = '1' 
        AND YEAR(i.InvDate) = '2017' AND i.ClientKey <> '11'
)
SELECT 
    YEAR(i.InvDate),  
    MONTH(i.InvDate), 
    COUNT(DISTINCT i.ClientKey) AS ClientCount 
FROM 
    [PROD].[dbo].[Invoices] i 
JOIN 
    CTE e ON e.ClientNumber = i.ClientKey 
WHERE 
    YEAR(i.InvDate) = 2017 
    AND i.ClientKey IN (CTE) 
GROUP BY 
    1, 2;
```

Result:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
>   Invalid column name 'CTE'.

Comment: What's the database engine? PostgreSQL, DB2, Sybase, etc. Looks like SQL Server or Sybase.

Comment: the `in (CTE)` just before the group by  appears incorrect.. Perhaps you mean e.clientNumber as CTE is a derrived table not a column?   but then this seems to be duplicating what the inner join does... do you even need the AND i.ClientKey in (CTE)?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the CTE comparison.

I have altered it as follows:

```
AND i.ClientKey IN (select ClientNumber from CTE)
```

---

```
WITH CTE (ClientNumber) AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        i.ClientKey AS ClientNumber 
    FROM 
        [PROD].[dbo].[Invoices] i  
    WHERE 
        MONTH(i.InvDate) = '1' 
        AND YEAR(i.InvDate) = '2017' 
        AND i.ClientKey <> '11'
)
SELECT
    YEAR(i.InvDate),  
    MONTH(i.InvDate), 
    COUNT(DISTINCT i.ClientKey) AS ClientCount 
FROM 
    [PROD].[dbo].[Invoices] i 
JOIN 
    CTE e ON e.ClientNumber = i.ClientKey 
WHERE 
    YEAR(i.InvDate) = 2017 
     AND i.ClientKey IN (SELECT ClientNumber FROM CTE) 
GROUP BY 
    1, 2;
```

Comment: Tried to amend the WHERE clause you suggested and got this... Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
The multi-part identifier "c.Name" could not be bound.

Comment: Please share the exact query you are using

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the select statement to include only the month and only group by month, but it still gave me an error...msg 164, each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference...also, i'm using SSMS if that helps.

```
WITH CTE (ClientName, ClientNumber) AS 
(SELECT DISTINCT c.Name, i.ClientKey AS ClientNumber
FROM .[NOW].[dbo].[Clients] c
JOIN  .[NOW].[dbo].[Invoices] i ON i.ClientKey = c.ClientKey
WHERE MONTH(i.InvDate) = '1' AND YEAR(i.InvDate) = '2018' AND i.ClientKey <> '11')

SELECT
MONTH(i.InvDate), 
COUNT (DISTINCT ClientName) AS ClientCount
FROM CTE e 
JOIN .[NOW].[dbo].[Invoices] i ON i.ClientKey = e.ClientNumber
WHERE i.ClientKey IN (SELECT ClientNumber FROM CTE)
GROUP BY 1;
```